# Only execute the insert function after passing the validate

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have the following code to validate if the form is filled out:

```js
$("#validate").on("click",function(){
    if(!$(".alerta").valid());
  });
  $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)" })
  $(".alerta").validate({
      messages: {
        Tipo: "Tipo de alerta obrigatório",
        Prioridade: {
              required: "Prioridade obrigatório"
          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="row g-3 alerta">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">TIPO DE ALERTA <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select chosen-select" name="Tipo" id="Tipo" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Teste</option>
    <option value="2">Teste1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">Prioridade <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select" name="Prioridade" id="Prioridade" required>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Prioridade</option>
    <option value="2">Prioridade1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-success" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 1%;" id="validate"> Enviar <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

After validation I created the code to insert into the database as follows:
To the form button I added this code `onclick="inserir_registo();"`

Then I created the function:

```
function inserir_registo(){
    var dadosajax = {
        'Tipo' : $("#Tipo").val(),
        'Prioridade' : $("#Prioridade").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'registo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(data)
        { 
            $('.alerta')[0].reset();
            Swal.fire('Boa!', 'Alerta enviado com sucesso!', 'success');
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I have is that when I click on the button to insert into the database, if it does not pass the validation, it inserts it into the database, only with the fields filled in.
You should only insert it when the form correctly passed the validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `insertIntoDB()` function is only called when the validation succeeds:

```
 $("#validate").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".alerta").valid()) insertIntoDB($("form.alerta"));
 });
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$("#validate").on("click", function() {
  if ($(".alerta").valid()) insertIntoDB($("form.alerta"));
});
$.validator.setDefaults({
  ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)"
})
$(".alerta").validate({
  messages: {
    Tipo: "Tipo de alerta obrigatório",
    Prioridade: "Prioridade obrigatório"
  }
});

function insertIntoDB($o){
 console.log($o.serializeArray())
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" class="row g-3 alerta">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">TIPO DE ALERTA <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select chosen-select" name="Tipo" id="Tipo" required>
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Teste</option>
      <option value="2">Teste1</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Tipo" class="form-label">Prioridade <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-select" name="Prioridade" id="Prioridade" required>
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Prioridade</option>
      <option value="2">Prioridade1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-success" style="float: right; margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 1%;" id="validate"> Enviar <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```